# How to get an unordered list to stay in one position even when the page is too small, resized

Tags: html, css

So my issue here is that I'm trying to keep my text in the center of the page (up a little bit).
Problem 1: When the page is resized, the unordered list moves up and down. I want it to stay in one position (on top of the mountain-ish). It looks like this:http://gyazo.com/8c7dc29c17dab86186cf4bfde4eb1a18

It should look like this: http://gyazo.com/644b3c072e7befffaf08d412a894bbb3
 So for example, when the page is very large it shows the unordered list way too low, but when the page is way too high it shows the unordered list at the top. There is a middle position where i want it to stay, here: http://gyazo.com/c4c70bf8b640c6c0c1848a7085be07cf
That is my goal here.

HTML:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Web_v2/css/Style.css">
<head><title>Company</title></head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>about us</li>
<li>Who we are</li>
<li>Contact us</li>


</ul>

</nav>

</body>

    <div id="bg">
<img src="../Web_v2/Assets/bg.jpg">
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
  #bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}
#bg img{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
nav{
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 20;

}
```

JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/5wdvk9k0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite complicated issue, better achieved with jQuery than CSS, but here you have a solution:

First, in your HTML, simplify things like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>about us</li>
        <li>filmography</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

you don't need that `#bg` div, we will target the `body`

Now, with cleaner markup, we'll use viweport sizesin our CSS like this:

```
body {
    background:url('http://cydronixfilms.com/css/images/bg.jpg') no-repeat 50%;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top:20vh
}
nav {
    font-family:"open sans";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 6vh;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 15vh;
    height: 20vh;
}
```

So what we did here is to make the `nav` element adjust to the viewport size, auto-adjusting fonts as well, and keeping the position at all times. This is called [CSS Device Adaptation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/). You can play around with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tk1d938/) so you see how it works, and you'll probably need to adjust some of the numbers, but there you have a way to do this with pure CSS

Comment: Works perfectly, but could you try explaining what the vw and vh are? I usually use something like #px or something of that sort.

Comment: it means viewport width and viewport height respectively and I have added a link that explains it in depth, but basically it's the width and height of the browser (not to confuse with the device). So, it will vary with device if browser is in full screen mode, but it will vary if you resize your browser as well, hence why I used this approach

Comment: Ah ok, also one last issue I'm having with this is that when the page is zoomed into (I could see this being an issue with mobile users) it shows some white space on the bottom and right side (http://gyazo.com/af5dffac91c7804480e9681e1007f9cd)

Comment: if you're testing on jsfiddle, pay no attention to it, because viewport sizes don't work well on iframes and jsfiddle uses iframes. Also, be sure to read the link because you'll need to use a meta tag that in your head element that prevents this kind of issue

Comment: I added the: <meta name="viewport" content="width=400, initial-scale=1"> but still showing white spaces when you scroll down and are zoomed into the page.

Comment: Ah i got it, i had to decrease the width to 50vw and the height to 100vh

Answer (score 0):

Your nav should be centered by making it a block with an auto margin right and margin left like so

```
nav{
    display: block;
    margin: 400px auto 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead like:

```css
*{margin:0;}
html, body{ height:100%; }
nav ul {list-style: none;}

#bg, nav{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0; 
}

#bg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url(http://cydronixfilms.com/css/images/bg.jpg) 50% / cover;
}

nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;    /* fallback for unsupported vh */
  height: 20vh;     /* CHANGE THIS ONE TO FIX VERTICAL POSITION */
  
  font-family:"open sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-size: 5vh;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
  
  
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>about us</li>
        <li>filmography</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Using a full background image and some `vh` (viewportHeight) units calculations you can get pretty awesome results.